# Como colocar um placeholder de dia, mês e ano no MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Preciso adicionar uma coluna de data da nota fiscal, essa sendo organizada por dia mês e ano (dd/mm/aa). Como eu faço pra deixar esse formato de tempo pré-estabelecido no MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Você quer deixar o formato `dd/mm/aa` ao invés do padrão do tipo de data do MySQL na hora do `select`?

Comment: Exatamente, isso mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você armazena suas datas com `datetime` ou `date` não tem jeito, tem que tratar no `select`. É bem simples:

```
SELECT data, DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y') as data_formatada
FROM tabela
ORDER BY data ASC
```

Esse script deve selecionar a data do jeito que é ( `data`), a data no formato dd/mm/YYYY (`data_formatada`) e ordena das mais antigas para as mais novas. Para inverter a ordenação, troque `ASC` por `DESC`.